# Use Custom CSS in Visual Web Part in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to use custom CSS in a Visual Web Part. CSS file is in
Style library like

`http://mysite:7/Style%20Library/SnehamCss.css`

Now in Visual Web Part I am trying to register this using

> `<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/Style Library/SnehamCss.css"
>   runat="server"></SharePoint:CssRegistration>,`

At the end Visual Web
part isn't rendering using the css defined in file. I have tried to
follow many blogs but its not helping.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Layout** mapped folder then use the *SharePoint:CssRegistration* in this way:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" Name="/_layout/SnehamCss.css" runat="server"></SharePoint:CssRegistration>
```

You can see [here](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/06/19/include-javascript-and-css-files-in-your-sharepoint-2010-visual-web-part/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `After="corev4.css"`:

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="/Style Library/SnehamCss.css" After="corev4.css" runat="server"></SharePoint:CssRegistration>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the .ascx file of the web part control add

`<link href="../../../_layouts/MyVisualWebParts/myStyleForWebPart.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

If you have mapped the Layouts folder then create your css file there. Then drag the CSS file from the Solution explorer onto the .ascx file. This automatically create the Link tag.